# Bootstrap 3.0 Product Carousel

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Reference: [See here for bootstrap 2.3.2 solution](https://gist.github.com/cfaddict/5770121)

Using the new Bootstrap 3.0 the above solution is no longer feasible

The result: [view 2.3.2's solution in 3.0](http://clip2net.com/clip/m236383/1378434086-clip-50kb.jpg?nocache=1)

Has anybody worked out how to get this working with 3.0 before I go and restyle everything >.<

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what you mean by no longer feasible, but there are several things you need to do to convert it to bootstrap 3,   first replace all row-fluid with just row.  Fluid rows no longer exist, as every row is fluid.

Replace every span(x)  for example you have span12, this will need to be replaced with col-md-12 or whatever size you want it to be.

If you still have issues post a jsbin with the code you have at that point and we can take a peek.

Comment: Also apparently we have all been doing bootstrap wrong for ages. You are supposed to not use those named classes and create your own classes using less mixins.

Comment: @extend FTW :), btw have you seen the SASS version of Bootstrap3 its pretty awesome.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a vertical carousel, you may have look here
Not sure about bootstrap Version support, but it works for me

[Tutorial Drive's Vertical Carousel](https://github.com/tutorialdrive/Bootstrap-Vertical-Thumbnail-Carousel)